# Anyone know how to add extra comma and string to array?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

i have a problem when i want to assign output into array string i already use str repace, etc but still not working..

i have output like this (in time)

$grapDate output = 09:00:0001:00:0012:00:0011:00:0010:00:0001:00:0000:00:0023:00:0022:00:00

```
date('H:i', strtotime($graph['Date'])
```

and the output become = 09:0001:0012:0011:0010:0001:0000:0023:0022:00

but i want to assign that become e.g $date = ['09:00','01:00', '12:00', etc]

because i want to use graph chart like this in my body

```
script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
    var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['$label'], //Jamnya
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(232,72,163,0.2)',
                borderColor: '#e848a3',
                label: '29 May 2020',
                data: [807,657,600,578,565,576,611,855,625,573,571,584,607,647,771,943,920,647,622,608,722,832,902,1062],
                fill: true,
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointHoverRadius: 10,
                showLine: true
            }]
        }, options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Total Online Yesterday',
                position: 'top',
                fontSize: 15,
                fontStyle: 'bold'
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            elements: {
                point: {
                    pointStyle: 'circle'
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'TIME'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        major: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            fontColor: '#FF0000'
                        }
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'TOTAL ONLINE'
                    }
                }]
            },
            tooltips:{
                callbacks: {
                    title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      return '29 May 2020 '+data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
                    },
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      return 'TOTAL : '+data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']]+'';
                    },
                },
                titleFontSize: 15,
                bodyFontSize: 15,
                displayColors: false
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

i still thinking how to assign parameter labels in class Chart become ['value', 'value', 'value']

Comment: So you want to do it in PHP or JS?

Comment: php broo because i get data from php. but i dont know if js can filter it

Comment: Show the loop where you use your function `date('H:i', strtotime($graph['Date'])` or method where you return this data.

Comment: The problem is that you are not returning the right way `json` or the way how you perform data concatenation.

Comment: `while ($i < mssql_num_rows($graph_count)) {
            $date = date('H:i', strtotime($graph_count['Date']));
            $convertDate = str_pad($date,6);
            $label = str_replace(' ',',',$convertDate);
            echo $date ;
            $i++;
        }`

Comment: Store date in a php array within while loop. Then outside loop json_encode() array before echo. In js, iterate through the json object to get date for chart

Answer (score 0):

First make each separate & print in JSON format.

```
$str = "09:0001:0012:0011:0010:0001:0000:0023:0022:00";
$date = json_encode(str_split($str, 5));
```

Comment: it become 
["11:00"]["09:00"]["01:00"]["12:00"]["11:00"]["10:00"]["01:00"]["00:00"]["23:00"]["22:00"]

Comment: It gives correct output, checked once :). Just paste here & check http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: but i dont know, i got that result

Comment: `$date = date('H:i', strtotime($graph['Date']));
                $date = json_encode(str_split($date, 5));`
i use that

Comment: What output you get after this `date('H:i', strtotime($graph['Date']));`

Comment: `11:0009:0001:0012:0011:0010:0001:0000:0023:0022:00` thatss.

Comment: and when i gettype. the result stringstringstringstringstring

Comment: Ohh..means you're using above line under loop. Try `json_encode(str_split($str, 5));` on your final string all dates :)

Comment: krkkk i dont understand bro ':(

Comment: `$graph_query = mssql_query("SELECT TOP 100 Convert(nvarchar,dtDate,108) AS Date, serial, nAverageUser, nMaxUser FROM tbl_ServerUser_Log ORDER BY serial DESC");`

`$i = 1;
            while ($graph = mssql_fetch_array($graph_query)) {
                $convert = json_encode(str_split($graph['Date'], 5));
                echo $convert;
                // $date = date('H:i', strtotime($graph['Date']));
                $i++;
               

             
            }`

Comment: is that what u mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214949/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-alexsandro-siregar).